# is there a way for a react native application to redirect me to a website

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to know how when launching my native react application, the application redirects me to a specific website
Example when I launch the application, I am redirected to https://www.google.com/ in the default browser
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, easily make your main page a full page WebView and give the url to it
for more info [check this link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview)

```
const App=()=>{
return(
<View style={{flex:1}}>
<WebView style={{flex:1}}/>
</View>
)
}
```